# [next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount]; Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findUnique')

Tags: mongodb, next.js, oauth-2.0, prisma, next-auth

I am making a sign up page with 3 providers (Twitter, Facebook and Instagram) using next-auth and prisma with mongoDB. The issue appears when I try to sign up with any of the providers. Here is my nextauth.js file.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

import InstagramProvider from "next-auth/providers/instagram";
import TwitterProvider from "next-auth/providers/twitter";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();


export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  
  providers: [
    InstagramProvider({
      clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    TwitterProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
      version: "2.0",
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),

  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  
});
```

I have tried to reinstall all the dependencies, because I don't see what else could be the problem. At first I thought it was the dependencies so I reinstall all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your adapter in the [nextauth].js file or wherever you are declaring the prisma instance.

Check out those similar discussions:

- https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4152
- [Integrating Prisma Adapter with Next Auth - Unexpected token 'export'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504346/integrating-prisma-adapter-with-next-auth-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: I found out that the error comes because of the prisma schema. I fixed it but now I can't cope with another error with probly comes from the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `@map("provider_account_id")` to the providerAccountId in the Account model in the schema.prisma file worked for me.

source: [bassem97's solution](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3815)

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually comes from the prisma schema. I fixed it after reading the next auth documentation about prisma and mongoDB.